# Combinations: How many handshakes?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I need help with the following question which I cannot seem to solve:

17 students are sitting in a circle. Each person shakes hands with everyone but his/her neighbours. How many handshakes have been exchanged?

My approach: no. of ways $ = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 14 = 7(15) = 105 $.

Apparently my answer is wrong (correct ans is 119). But I can't seem to understand why. Could someone please explain?

Comment: The reason why this is wrong is as follows: the first person has 14 people to shake hands with. The second person **as well** has 14 people to shake hands with, since he wouldn't shake hands with his neighbour anyway! So, the sum is 14+(14+13+...+1), which does add up to 119.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each of 17 people shakes hands with 14 people (all except themselves and their 2 neighbors), so there are

$$\frac{17\times 14}{2} = 119$$

handshakes (dividing by 2 to account for symmetry, as you would otherwise count *"$A$ shaking hands with $B$"* and *"$B$ shaking hands with $A$"* as distinct events).

Comment: Does it mean that we don't care about how they sit, say in a circle or in a row?

Comment: @LeeKM: The difference is that in a circle, everyone has two neighbors, while in a row, the first and last person have only one each.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that I misunderstood the quuestion. I thought that the handshakes were to be made with distinct persons.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way to think about it.

If everyone shook hands with everyone you'd have $\frac {17*16}2 = 136$ handshakes (divide by 2 because the above is double counting A shaking hands with B and so forth).

However, there are $\frac {17*2}2 = 17$ handshakes that aren't happening because neighbors aren't shaking hands (2 neighbors for each of the 17 people, again divided by 2 to remove duplicates).

So $136-17 = 119$

Pew's response is a little more direct, but finding the number by calculating the total possibilities minus the "not allowed" interactions is sometimes a little more intuitive for some people.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of this in graph theory as the following:

---

$G$ has $17$ vertices with degree $14$, since there are no loops(people self handshaking), and no vertices are adjacent to the vertices beside them. So total degree is $17\times 14$.

We know that degree is equal to $2\times\text{number of edges}$ and hence there are $\frac{17\times 14}{2}=119$ edges in total, where edges represent handshakes.

Answer (score 1):

As is typical for problems with big numbers, you should *always* resort to a smaller number if you can't solve the full problem.

Here, 17 people at the table is a bit hard to imagine immediately.

Let's start with 3 people at the table.

How many handshakes now?

There are zero.

What about 4 people:

```
A B

C D
```

A can't shake with B or C, B can't with A or D, D can't with B or C, C can't with A or D--only A & D and B & C can shake.

So 2 shakes:

```
A B
 X
C D
```

5 people is when it gets interesting, and when you should be able to see the pattern:

```
      B

  A       C

    D   E
```

Everyone has two people they can't shake with, leaving two shakes per person--but we overcount by just multiplying 5 & 3, so we divide by two.

This is easiest to see by trying to draw the graph mentioned by @Commitingtoachalleng -- draw a line between any people who can shake hands:

```
        B
       / \
  A-----------C   (also C-D & A-E--a 5-point star)
     /     \
    D       E
```

So we hypothesize the answer is $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$. Note that this formula holds for $n=3$ and $n=4$ as well, as we'd hope!

One final way to see this is to look again at the graphs--

you might notice that they're always complete graphs (every vertex connected to every other vertex) with the outer edges removed.

Since there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges in a complete graph on $n$ vertices (which you can confirm yourself by a similar process), and $n$ outer edges,

there must be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - n = \frac{n^2-n-2n}{2} = \frac{n(n-3)}{2}$ handshakes.

However you cut it, there are $\frac {17 \cdot 14} 2 = 119$ total handshakes.

Comment: We should also point out that the second option (working backwards from complete graphs) is the graph analogue of @Duncan's solution

Answer (score -1):

I will explain for 6, same logic applies for all the numbers.

first, 
if 6 persons shakes will all in the party, then number of shakes will be:

A  B  C  D  E  F

A can shake with only rest of 5 persons(B,C,D,E,F) i.e, right side ppl. = 5

B can shake with only his right sides(C,D,E,F) ppl(not with A bcos,A already shook with B just now. so no repeat) = 4

C can shake with only his right sides(D,E,F) ppl(not with A&B bcos,A&B already shook with C just now. so no repeat) = 3

D can shake with only his right sides(E,F) ppl(not with left side ppl  bcos, they already shook with D just now. so no repeat) = 2

E can shake with only his right sides(F) ppl(not with left side ppl  bcos, they already shook with E just now. so no repeat) = 1

as all of the persons shook hand with F, He dont shake with any one now.

So total possible shakes for 6 persons are = 5+4+3+2+1 => 15

now in questions it is given that, No one shakes hand with neighbors.

[Imagine ppls sitting around table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVzqa.png)

```
        A   B
      F       C
        E   D
```

Please treat above image as 6 Ppl around circle :
So now,

**Invalid Shakes:**

A cannot shake with B,F . I am representing it as below :
  A  -no- B & F    => 2 invalid shakes.
  B  -no- C only. Bcos  B -no- A is covered as part of first case.
                   =>  1 invalid shake
  C  -no- D only.  =>  1 invalid shake
  D  -no- E only.  =>  1 invalid shake
  E  -no- F only.  =>  1 invalid shake
  F dont shake with A is already covered as part of first invalid shakes.

so total invalid shakes are 2+1+1+1+1 = 6

so for 6 ppl:  out of  total 15 , 6 are invalid. So 15-6 = 9

on the same line :

for 17 ppl:  out of  total (16+15+...+1)=136 , 17 are invalid. So 136-17 = 119

shortcut :   For N ppl, Total shakes are  (N-1)(first term + last term)/2  *Arithmetic progression sum*. out of which Invalids are N.
So valid shakes =>  (Total - N)

Comment: What is the point of posting such a complex answer to a question with a simple **and accepted** answer posted almost four years ago?